# Facebook share cant unselect to less than two images.

Tags: facebook

When pasting a link to an external blog on my Facebook Page (not my private facebook, but a PAGE that i am admin for) the blog's images comes up in the share window. I can unselect an image by pressing the X in the upper right corner, but when there is 2 images left, i cant unselect any more. Is this a feature or bug ? I have tested with different blogs both with or without og:image tags and it is the same behavior.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn’t seem to be a programming question. // For Facebook end user support, please refer to their Help section. Forms to report broken features can be found in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by facebook the following day